# RF24 system fails after RPI system update - any ideas?

Tags: raspbian-jessie, update, nrf24l01

I have a number of raspberry Pi's (2 and 3's all running Jessie), which happily talked to themselves and arduinos via RF24s, based around the setup described in the link below (git clone https://github.com/Blavery/lib_nrf24).

http://invent.module143.com/daskal_tutorial/raspberry-pi-3-wireless-pi-to-arduino-communication-with-nrf24l01/

The structure of the communication is that the broadcasting unit sends a short message and the receiver then confirms receipt via a confirmation message (no auto ACK etc). Everything worked fine until a mid-September 2017 when several of the RPIs automatically ran a monthly sudo apt-get upgrade, sudo apt-get dist-upgrade and sudo rpi-update and then restarted. Since then the transmission and confirmation have been impossible. A third Pi was not set to automatically update and that continues to send and confirm messages just fine.

The non-functional Pi's generate the following output...

STATUS   = 0x03 RX_DR=0 TX_DS=0 MAX_RT=0 RX_P_NO=1 TX_FULL=1
RX_ADDR_P0-1     =
 0xfefefefefc 0xfefefefefc
RX_ADDR_P2-5     =
0xf8
0xf9
0xf9
0xf9

TX_ADDR      =
 0xfefefefefc
RX_PW_P0-6   =
0x04
0x04
0x00
0x00
0x00
0x00

EN_AA        =
0x0f

EN_RXADDR    =
0x00

RF_CH        =
0x1f

RF_SETUP     =
0x01

CONFIG       =
0x13

DYNPD/FEATURE    =
0x00
0x00

Data Rate    = 1MBPS
Model        = nRF24L01
CRC Length   = Disabled
PA Power     = PA_MIN

Any suggestions as to what might be causing the problem and how I might be able to get these pi's to communicate again?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please consider editing your question to improve readability.

Comment: Update was mid-August not mid-September - apologies...

Comment: Hi, did you ever get it working?